# Im trying to create a clock (military). Using a for loop to count every tick of time until the time reaches 5pm. How should the for loop be set up?

Tags: java

I need to create a clock that counts every tick of second of a day. From 9am - 5pm. How should my for loop look if I'm trying to count every tick of the day between 9am and 5pm?

```
ArrayList<Teller> tellerList = new ArrayList<Teller>();
         for(int i = 0; i < amountTeller; i++)
         {
             tellerList.add(new Teller(i + 1));  
         }

         //inner for loop does 1 tick of time
         for(int k = 1; k > 480; k++)
         {

             ??????


         for(int t = 0; t < tellerList.size(); t++)
         {
             //calculate times (wait time and proc time)
             Teller currTeller = tellerList.get(t);
             if(currTeller.hasClient())
             {
                 currTeller.Dequeque();
             }
             tellerList.set(t, currTeller);
         }
         }
```

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Comment: How should your loop look? No idea. You do need to be getting the time (System.currentTimeMillis) at the very least. Take a look at ScheduledExecutorService: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Comment: Before there were executor services, you would have done something like `Thread.sleep(1000); processTick();` but it's actually more complicated than that, as this loop ends up taking more than 1 second to process your your timer starts to lag.